# Errors returning the correct value at indecie

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, google-sheets, gspread

**EDITS AT BOTTOM**

*I am only posting a portion of my code that is relevant to my question, as I am working with about 300 lines of code right now and growing rapidly.*

**My Error:**

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid requests[0].addSheet: A sheet with the name "Elijah Skinner" already exists. Please enter another name.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

**My Thoughts:**

I think the issue is that getUser() is not returning the correct value. Im not sure if its because I need to use enumerate or if it's when I get the index.

**My Code:**

```
import gspread
import pandas as pd
from gspread import worksheet
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime

# authorize the clientsheet 
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# get the instance of the Spreadsheet
sheet = client.open('Punch Card Systems')

# get the first sheet of the Spreadsheet
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(0)

# get the total number of columns
sheet_instance.col_count

# get the value at the specific cell
sheet_instance.cell(col=3, row=2)


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, email, timeCard, payRate):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.email = email
        self.timeCard = {}
        self.payRate = 15
        self.clockedIn = False


p1 = Employee("Elijah", "Skinner", "email@gmail.com", timeStamp(), 15.00)


fullName = (p1.firstName + " " + p1.lastName)


def getUser():
    for r in range(1, sheet_instance.row_count - 1):
        row = sheet_instance.row_values(r)
        if row[0] == fullName:
            print(row[0])
            return row[0]


if fullName == getUser():
    sheet_runs = sheet.get_worksheet(fullName)
    worksheet.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)

if fullName != getUser():
    sheet.add_worksheet(rows=20, cols=20, title=fullName)
    worksheet.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)
```

The second if statement successfully creates a new worksheet with the correct name, but my update_cell line is not working; I am more concerned about the first if statement though.

The error I pasted above is what I get when I run the program after the worksheet has been created. It is skipping the first if statement completely. Which tells me ( I Think) that getUser() is returning the wrong value.

On the otherhand though, when I print the index value using this `print(row[0])`, It prints the correct value that I am searching for no matter what. If it is returning the correct value, then does that mean that my if statement is the problem?

**EDITS:**

I just tried this instead to see if it would return the correct value I need:

```
def getUser():
    for r in range(1, sheet_instance.row_count - 1):
        row = sheet_instance.row_values(r)
        if row[0] == fullName:
            print(row[0])
            name = row[0]
    return name
```

And I received this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

############################

```
def getUser():
    for r in range(1, sheet_instance.row_count - 1):
        row = sheet_instance.row_values(r)
        if row[0] == fullName:
            print(row[0])
            return row[0]


if fullName == getUser():
    sheet_runs = sheet.get_worksheet(fullName)
    sheet_runs.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)

if fullName != getUser():
    sheet.add_worksheet(rows=20, cols=20, title=fullName)
    sheet_runs.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)
```

I think I am returning the correct value know but I am getting this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Honestly, this just confuses me more. It is printing the correct response but isnt sending it. Is it because when I print, it is still on that index?

#####################################

```
def getUser():
    for r in range(1, sheet_instance.row_count + 1):
        row = sheet_instance.row_values(r)
        if row[r] == fullName:
            print(row[0])
            return True


if getUser():
    sheet_runs = sheet.get_worksheet(fullName)
    sheet_runs.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)
else:
    sheet.add_worksheet(rows=20, cols=20, title=fullName)
    sheet_runs = sheet.get_worksheet(fullName)
    sheet_runs.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)
#############################################
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try to create a self-contained piece of code that someone else could run, without modification, to see the problem. It's not even clear what libraries you are using, or what *problem you are trying to solve*. Please try to *ask a question*, instead of just talking through the code, the error messages, and your thought process

Comment: Thank you for the input. I will update accordingly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Should be good to go now. I added everything but the tkinter code and some sensitive info. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: My question is why isn't the if statement ```if fullName == getUser():``` working correctly and how can I fix it

Comment: Then the next step is to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code. For example, what value do you actually get back from `getUser`? What sorts of values do you expect to get back, and under what conditions? Does it work as expected?

Comment: It seems like the general approach of your code is that you want to check the name of the `sheet_instance` by looking at  the rows of data. I don't understand why you expect this to work. It also seems that when you don't get a match this way, your plan is to add a worksheet to the spreadsheet, titling it with the Employee's name. But... this doesn't cause the `sheet_instance` to change.

Comment: `getUser()` is either going to return `fullName` or `None`.  If all you're doing is validating the name, you can just return True or False.  Is `sheet_instance` supposed to contain your list of sheet names?  Exactly where do you get the TypeError?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have  thought about doing the boolean for getUser. I just havent done that yet, I will go ahead and do that now though. sheet_instance is currently set to the main worksheet that contains a list of employees, it's bad naming on mypart because sheet_instance will only ever be the first sheet. I created sheet_runs to be the one that changes depending on fullName. That could be a bad idea, but I am new to all of this. The bad names are mostly from me copy and pasting and not going back to change it. 

 I will add to my post with my updates.

Comment: @TimRoberts The typeError is located here: 
```sheet_runs = sheet.get_worksheet(fullName)```
```get_worksheet properties = sheet_data["sheets"][index]["properties"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: @KarlKnechtel To answer your question about what I get back, that is why I threw in the print statement and it is giving me the correct response I am looking for everytime.

Comment: @TimRoberts To be more precise, it seems like it is from this sheet_runs = sheet.get_worksheet(fullName). Ive looked up ways to get a worksheet and the options are:
by index, and by title.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Tim in the comments, I updated my getUser() function to boolean since that is all I needed it for. That cleared a lot up. To fix the type errors I was getting, I changed get_worksheet to worksheet. Since I already had all of the sheets included, I did not need to get it again.

**UPDATED WORKING CODE**

```
fullName = (p1.firstName + " " + p1.lastName)
currentUserSheet = sheet.worksheet(fullName)

def getUser():
    for r in range(1, sheet_instance.row_count + 1):
        row = sheet_instance.row_values(r)
        if row[0] == fullName:
            print(row[0])
            return True


if getUser():
    print("It WORKS")
    #currentUserSheet.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)
else:
    sheet.add_worksheet(rows=20, cols=20, title=fullName)
    #currentUserSheet.update_cell(1, 1, p1.timeCard)
```

The cell updates are commented out because p1.timecard is an invalid format for google sheets.